# CSS fails to position menu block as desired during hover

Tags: css

My left side block contains a vertical menu plus other items above and below. The primary menu items are visible. I want a block of secondary menus to become visible and be shifted (down and right) when hovering over a primary menu item. All of this should be achievable using CSS.

When I set the style to `position: absolute` the secondary menus all show in the same position instead of vertically below the active link.

When I set the style to `position: relative` the secondary menus show in the correct location but the lower primary menus are shifted down, changing the size of my left hand block.

Is there a way to overlay the secondary menu blocks in the correct location?

The relevant CSS is:

```
.nav
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-right: 1px hidden #54879d; 
    z-index: 20;
}

.nav li
{
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;  /* Removes the default styling (bullets) for the list */
    font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size:1.00em;
    padding: 0 0 15px 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.nav a
{                           
    border-left: 1px hidden #54879d;
    border-right: 1px hidden #1f5065;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
}

.nav li ul
{
    display: none;  /* Hides the drop-down menu */
    height: auto;                                   
    margin: 0; /* Aligns drop-down box underneath the menu item */
    padding: 1px; /* Aligns drop-down box underneath the menu item */           
}               

.nav li:hover ul
{
    display: block; /* Displays the drop-down box when the menu item is hovered over */
    position: relative; //absolute;
    top: 1em;
    left: 50px;
    background-color: LightSlateGray;
}

.nav li ul li
{
    width: 150px;
}

.nav li ul li a
{
    border-left: 1px hidden #1f5065; 
    border-right: 1px hidden #1f5065; 
    border-top: 1px hidden #74a3b7; 
    border-bottom: 1px hidden #1f5065; 
}

.nav li ul li a:hover   { background-color: rgb(180, 0, 0); }
```

Typical HTML is like this but may have a varying number of inner primary menu items and secondary menu items:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class=" active ">
        <a href="firstpage" id="link">Overview</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="dropdown inactive " id="itemContainer">
            <a href="secondmenu?3#" id="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Terms</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="seondsinglepage" id="link">New Term</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="secondmultiplepage" id="link">View Terms</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="dropdown inactive " id="itemContainer">
            <a href="thirdmenu?3#" id="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Classes</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="secondsinglepage" id="link">New Class</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="secondmultiplepage" id="link">View Classes</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="j_spring_security_logout" id="logout_link">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:
.nav li {position: relative;}
which will set a relative position for it's child elements - namely your sub-menu.

and then,
.nav li:hover ul {position: absolute; z-index:1;}
to position your sub-menu outside of the inline layout amd the z-index: 1 placing it above the z-index of your main menu.